# Azure Deserialize JSON Response C#

Tags: c#

I try to deserialize my JSON Response which is at below, but when i print the content of each parameter, it shows error.

My JSON Resposne:

```
[
{
  "faceRectangle": {
     "top": 214,
     "left": 472,
     "width": 450,
     "height": 450
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
     "age": 19.0,
     "emotion": {
        "anger": 0.0,
        "contempt": 0.0,
        "disgust": 0.0,
        "fear": 0.0,
        "happiness": 0.0,
        "neutral": 0.996,
        "sadness": 0.003,
        "surprise": 0.001
     }
  }
}
]
```

I able to deserialize my code with this:

```
public static async Task<List<RootObject>> MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Request headers.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

        // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
        string requestParameters = "&returnFaceId=false&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,emotion";

        // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
        string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body. Posts a locally stored JPEG image.
        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
            // The other content types you can use are "application/json"
            // and "multipart/form-data".
            content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            // Execute the REST API call.
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            // Get the JSON response.
            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // Display the JSON response.
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n");
            string format = JsonPrettyPrint(contentString);
            var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(format);
            Console.WriteLine(format);
            Console.WriteLine(deserializedJson);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit...");
            return deserializedJson;
        }
    }
```

But when i try to print each parameter value, it shows error:

```
var output1 = MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath).Result;
                var x= output1[0].FaceAttributes.Emotion.Anger;
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                var y = output1[1].FaceAttributes.Emotion.Neutral;
                Console.WriteLine(y);
                if (x >= 0.5)
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"D:\Degree course outline\FYP2019\soft.wav");
                    player.Play();
                }
                if (y>= 0.5)
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"D:\Degree course outline\FYP2019\soft.wav");
                    player.Play();
                }
```

My error code is like this:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

How could i solve it?
Thanks

My class object:

```
class Program
{

    public class FaceRectangle
    {
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

    public class Emotion
    {
        public double Anger { get; set; }
        public double Contempt { get; set; }
        public double Disgust { get; set; }
        public double Fear { get; set; }
        public double Happiness { get; set; }
        public double Neutral { get; set; }
        public double Sadness { get; set; }
        public double Surprise { get; set; }
    }

    public class FaceAttributes
    {
        public double Age { get; set; }
        public Emotion Emotion { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public FaceRectangle FaceRectangle { get; set; }
        public FaceAttributes FaceAttributes { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var output1 = await MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath);
if (output1 != null && output1.Count > 0)
{ 
    var x= output1[0].FaceAttributes.Emotion.Anger;
     Console.WriteLine(x);
}
if (output1 != null && output1.Count > 1)
{
    var y = output1[1].FaceAttributes.Emotion.Neutral;
}
```

The out of range exception is there because your deserialized output does not have enough elements to access. Please share your class object for more help.

Also try to avoid using the `.Result` to get the return value from asynch as it could lead to deadlocks.

**Edit after providing class**

With your class being like this then change your code accordingly:

```
var output1 = await MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath);
if (output1 != null && output1.Count > 0)
{ 
    var x= output1[0].FaceAttributes.Emotion.Anger;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    var y = output1[0].FaceAttributes.Emotion.Neutral;
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```

There is only one `RootObject` in your jsons array that is comprised of two others.

Json array `[]` object `{}`

An array with two objects looks like this `[{},{}]` and not like this `[{{},{}}]`

Comment: My class is like this, i edited the post.  when i used this statement "var Emo = await FaceEmotion.MakeAnalysisRequest(imageFilePath);". It still showed errors

Comment: yeah, it did! Thank you very much. But i still blur with the explanation. Is it because my JSON Response is in [ { {},{} } ] , so i have only one object? As a result, i only can put array [0]?

Comment: It is exactly that!

Comment: Bro, Thanks a lot!